# SQL Count with a Join

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select product_name, product_order.Count(*)
From product Join product_order
ON product.product_id = product_order.product_id
where product.product_id = product_order.product_id;
```

I have been working on this query for an hour and can't seem to get it to work. All I need to do is take the product from one table match it to how many times it was ordered in another. Then display the product in one column and how many times it was ordered in the next.

Comment: This has nothing to do with PL/SQL which is a procedural language in Oracle DBMS. This is mere SQL. Is your DBMS Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be as simple as:

```
  select product_name,
         count(product_order.product_id)
    From product left join product_order
      on product.product_id = product_order.product_id
group by product_name
```

I used a left join and counted on product_order.product_id so products that have not been ordered will still display, with a count of zero.

Comment: Is this not missing a group by?

Comment: @Chrisrs2292 Why yes .. yes it is!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
select p.product_name,
       (select count(*) from product_order po where p.product_id = po.product_id) times_ordered
from   product p
```

Alternatively, you could use a group by statement:

```
select p.product_name,
       count(po.product_id)
from   product p,
       product_order po
where  p.product_id = po.product_id(+)
group by p.product_name
```

Comment: I admit that Oracle was *very* late when they finally introduced explicit joins in 2001. But this was fourteen years ago. I don't see why you'd still want to use the old error-prone comma-separated join syntax. Apart from that a good answer.

Comment: Personally I just use it for consistency with other developers in my office and preference. My brain just doesn't like how the ANSI syntax reads, although I know many people prefer it.

Comment: And yet if you need to use a full outer join, or any of the subtle varieties of join that the old syntax doesn't support, you have to use it anyway.

Comment: Even Oracle recommends to **not** use the proprietary `(+)`  operator and use standard `left join` instead.